# How can I access a Facebook page's events from website backend?

Tags: node.js, web, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am building a website for my band and I would like to display upcoming events on it.
When I send a request from NodeJS to the Facebook Graph API (`/{page-id}/events`) with the app's token, I get a response back saying

`(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.`

Is there a way to get this information without getting a business verification and app review?

It doesn't make sense to me that I would need that high level of permission as the information page is public and events can be retrieved by browser without even being logged in to Facebook.

Comment: For a page you are admin of, you should not need these permissions, the user or page access token should do. And the permissions to grant API access to your own page should no require review or business verification, as long as you are only using the app yourself.

Comment: @CBroe This is exactly the problem. I would need a page token (for which I would need a user token) to access the data, which is not possible to acquire (or would be very hacky) from the backend. Is there really no way to access it with an app token?

Comment: No. You won't get Page Public Content Access granted for the purpose of only accessing your own page, and its allowed usage is only to "Provide competitive benchmark analysis" to begin with, according to docs.

Comment: I don't see what is "hacky" about implementing Facebook login. You get your user token with the necessary permissions via that, then you get an extended page token, and you are good to go for up to 60 days.

Comment: If all that's too much trouble, then you are left with the option to use the page plugin, with the events tab showing. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: @CBroe I'm not implementing Facebook login whose only purpose is retrieving my page's events. That would be a terrible user experience, I don't get why Facebook forces this for public events on a public page.
I had zero trouble with YouTube's API for a similar thing.
You can take a look at the page to get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish https://jpbb-dev.herokuapp.com/en#concerts

Comment: I am not talking about implementing it for the visitors of your site, I am talking about implementing it so that the page admin can generate the necessary token from the backend ...